# Why Enter key in application built in jdeveloper 11g in adf table set method will run but in jdeveloper 12c set method java will not trigger

Tags: jdeveloper

I work jdeveloper 11g with adf tabular and when enter a value and press Enter key the java code in set method of the entity triggers and run but when i upgrade to 12c Enter key dose not run the code

I try to find any proberity to resolve this and compare 11 g with 12c but didn't find anything

Comment: Can you tell us the exact 11g and 12c versions you are using?

Comment: Versions : 12.2.1.3.0.  11.1.2.0.0